# How to make my entire popover backgorund color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is the arrow thing in my popover didn't change and its still color white.

current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/19/

css:

```
.popover {
    background: #BE7979;
    color: white;
    border-bottom-color: #BE7979;
    border-top-color: #BE7979;
    border-left-color: #BE7979;
    border-right-color: #BE7979;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy9LQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your this css selector like this:

```
.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #BE7979;     <-----------// replace white color to #BE7979
    border-top-width: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    top: 1px;
}

.popover.top > .arrow {
   border-bottom-width: 0;
   border-top-color: #BE7979;
   bottom: -11px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -11px;
}

.popover.right > .arrow:after {
   border-left-width: 0;
   border-right-color: #BE7979;
   bottom: -10px;
   content: " ";
   left: 1px;
}

.popover.left > .arrow:after {
    border-left-color: #BE7979;
    border-right-width: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    content: " ";
    right: 1px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy9LQ/)

Comment: if i add a new input with popover data-placement top it doesnt work here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy9LQ/1/

Comment: you have to overwrite other selector as well here it is:http://jsfiddle.net/3bXMN/

Comment: ``.popover.top > .arrow {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-top-color: #BE7979;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
}``

Comment: what about the left and right data-placement popover what part of it in css should i change?

Comment: you provide them in fiddle then i can tell using firebug inspector

Comment: Thanks dude..i didnt know i need to change that much in css to be able to change my popover background.

Comment: actually this css written for some theme and you have changed theme right so you need to do changes in the css where needed

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the arrow element with fire-bug:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

and you would be able to see the css as below:

```
.popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #BE7979;//changed the color here which was previously #FFFFFF
    border-top-width: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below class will turn it to the desired color

```
.popover.bottom>.arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: #BE7979;
}
```